# Bluetooth + simulating mouse

Tags: android, bluetooth, mouse

anyone know if its posible to make an application to simulate a touchscreen mouse or trackpad by bluetooth??

How can I make that the PC (or MAC) knows me as a mouse device?

Regards,
     Juan

Comment: Good question, well stated even, some speak of knowing, but cannot think about what you don't know. +1 Buddy

Comment: Try [GlovePIE](http://glovepie.org/). Great program.

Comment: found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the Bluetooth HID specification. It may be possible, depending on the stack of the device that you are using to emulate a mouse/trackpad. I'm not familiar with the stack on Android (assuming that's the platform you're using from the tag on your question) so I don't know if it's possible from there.

Essentially, you create a HID service on the L2CAP protocol. The service record specifies the HID descriptors which describe the data being sent from emulating device.  The HID driver on the host computer should be able to interpret that data.

It might be useful to try to connect to another Bluetooth mouse/trackpad from the desktop (Bluecove on a stack other than Microsoft is a good way to hack around in Bluetooth). Have a look at the service record for the HID service on the mouse/trackpad. Also, look at the data coming from the mouse/trackpad for an idea of what needs to be sent and when.

Alternatively, you could write a server application on your computer that communicates via another Bluetooth protocol (e.g., RFCOMM/SPP) to the input-device emulator app running on your phone. The server application would simulate the input device (e.g., move the mouse pointer around on the screen, etc).

Comment: there are endless issues with L2CAP and SDP on Android. On some devices, using BlueZ, it is possible to use them via native code / JNI , but the standard SDK doesn't support them.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating your own project why dont you contribute to the [remotedroid](http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid) project?

I'm assuming you know your bluetooth api's well. Remote droid uses Wifi and OSC messaging to communicate with the PC.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 
I didn't know remotedroid project. My intention is using bluetooth so we don't depends on network.
I'm going to try both things.

Regards.

Comment: The project owner did not add BT support to remote droid because he did not have a device with him. You can always contribute if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may use GlovePie with the wiimote connected to BlueSoeil, It will alow you to do anything with you computer with the wiimote. It also has a Language it uses

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:
[Serverless Bluetooth Keyboard & Mouse for PC/Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek&hl=gsw&gl=US)

<strike>It's even [open-source](https://github.com/AppGround-io/bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-support)!</strike>

Unfortunately it is not open source, it just has a GitHub readme for some reason.
But still the app is quite good!

Comment: The GitHub repository does not contain any source code. So this app is clearly not open source. Is this some kind of weird fishing attack?